# calling out to rbenv gemset

Tags: ruby, resque, rbenv

On a server I want to install a series of gems that got uploaded into a newly created gemset. This installation should be done from a resque worker.

The purpose of creating the gemset is to execute some of the gems that got uploaded in an environment similar to the users machine.

I don't understand 100% how rbenv works and that is really causing some headaches.

Any ideas on how I can solve this problem would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout [chgems](https://github.com/postmodern/chgems#readme). chgems is like `chroot` for RubyGems. chgems can spawn a sub-shell or run a command with `PATH`, `GEM_HOME`, `GEM_PATH` set to install gems into `$directory/.gem/$ruby/$version/`.

```
$ chgems $directory gem install $user_gem
$ chgems $directory $user_command
```